# Algorithm to print all solutions of equation

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode, combinatorics, equation

I have this problem:

Assume that we have this simple equation

```
x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 = 20
```

and I want to **print all non-negative integer solutions** of this equation and i must use only numbers `3, 4, 5, 6`

for example:

```
0 + 4 + 4 + 6 + 6 = 20
etc.
```

I dont want write it in specific programming language, only in pseudo-code

Any idea?

Comment: There are infinite number of solutions to that equation. Do you mean you want to print all non-negative integer solutions?

Comment: YES, all non-negative :)

Comment: do you want to eliminate duplicates? for e.g. `15 + 1 + 2 + 1 + 1` and `15 + 1 + 1 + 2 + 1` will one value be eliminated or both kept

Comment: I want to keep duplicates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In java code

```
    int []numbers = {0, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    int res=20;
    int sum=0;

    for(int i:numbers)
        for(int j:numbers)
            for(int k:numbers)
                for(int l:numbers)
                    for(int m:numbers) {
                        sum = i + j + k + l + m;
                        if(sum==res) {
                        String solution = i + " " + j + " " + k + " " + l +" " + m;
                        Log.i("solution", "---- " + solution);}
                    }
```

In pseudo code is something like this:

```
FOR each number1 in the number_list
    FOR each number2 in the number_list
        FOR each number3 in the number_list
            FOR each number4 in the number_list
                FOR each number5 in the number_list
                    sum = number1+number2+number3+number4+number5;
                    IF sum IS EQUAL TO 20 THEN
                        Print number1, number2, number3, number4, number5
                    ENDIF
                ENDFOR
            ENDFOR
        ENDFOR
    ENDFOR
ENDFOR
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work:
[Finding all possible combinations of numbers to reach a given sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632322/finding-all-possible-combinations-of-numbers-to-reach-a-given-sum)

You can start the set of numbers as [3,4,5,6]  and not to remove the element once chosen and check by the depth of recursion if you got exactly the needed number of elements.

This is more generic and will allow to resolve equations with different number of elements without the need to add/remove nested loops.

Comment: Then you cannot use 0 and all the solutions are non-negative by definition.